# Why sometimes the same variables declaration gives a compilation error?

Tags: vba

When there is a variable type mismatch compilation error in VBA sometimes the solution is to change how I declare the variables, but not the type.
e.g.: 
If I have:

```
Dim numCables, numCaColumn, firstCableRow, numCable, numDiColumn, posInArray, j, numMaterialWDifSEColumn, numSEMaterials  As Integer
```

And I replace it for:

```
Dim numCables, numCaColumn, firstCableRow, numCable, numDiColumn, posInArray, j, numMaterialWDifSEColumn  As Integer
Dim numSEMaterials As Integer
```

Now with this change I don't have a compilation error and all is working fine.

I would like to know why this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: This question pops up all the time, but in such a way that it is seldom an outright duplicate. Arguably VBA made a poor design decision here, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In variable declaration, you must specify the type for each variable, otherwise it's a `Variant`.

In other words, in

```
Dim numCables, numCaColumn, firstCableRow, numCable, numDiColumn, posInArray, j, numMaterialWDifSEColumn, numSEMaterials  As Integer
```

only `numSEMaterials` is an `Integer` and the rest are `Variant`s.

You need

```
 Dim numCables as Integer, numCaColumn as Integer, firstCableRow as Integer...
```

Note (thanks for the reminder [@John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman)) that it's almost always better to use a `Long` variable type instead of `Integer`. For a detailed explanation, see [Why use integer instead of Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Answer (score 1):

Vba code like `Dim a, b, c as integer` does NOT declare a, b and c as integer type! It does only declare c as integer. The variables a and b are declared as variant!

To declare all variables as integer you have to decare each one individually:

```
Dim a as integer
Dim b as integer
Dim c as integer
```

.

**PROOF**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Debug_VarType()

Dim a, b, c As Integer

Debug.Print "Definition of a, b and c:"
Debug.Print "a: "; VarType(a); MyVarType(VarType(a))
Debug.Print "b: "; VarType(b); MyVarType(VarType(b))
Debug.Print "c: "; VarType(c); MyVarType(VarType(c))
Debug.Print ""

Dim d As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim f As Integer

Debug.Print "Definition of d, e and f:"
Debug.Print "d: "; VarType(d); MyVarType(VarType(d))
Debug.Print "e: "; VarType(e); MyVarType(VarType(e))
Debug.Print "f: "; VarType(f); MyVarType(VarType(f))
Debug.Print ""

End Sub


Function MyVarType(Varint As Integer) As String
Select Case Varint
    Case 0: MyVarType = "vbEmpty"
    Case 1: MyVarType = "vbNull"
    Case 2: MyVarType = "vbInteger"
    Case 3: MyVarType = "vbLong"
    Case 4: MyVarType = "vbSingle"
    Case 5: MyVarType = "vbDouble"
    Case 6: MyVarType = "vbCurrency"
    Case 7: MyVarType = "vbDate"
    Case 8: MyVarType = "vbString"
    Case 9: MyVarType = "vbObject"
    Case 10: MyVarType = "vbError"
    Case 11: MyVarType = "vbBoolean"
    Case 12: MyVarType = "vbVariant"
    Case 13: MyVarType = "vbDataObject"
    Case 14: MyVarType = "vbDecimal"
    Case 17: MyVarType = "vbByte"
    Case 20: MyVarType = "vbLongLong"
    Case 36: MyVarType = "vbUserDefinedType"
    Case 8192: MyVarType = "vbArray"
End Select
End Function
```

[image]